# Função .not() não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Eu tenho o seguinte código `HTML`:

```
<div id="mini-cart" class="mini-cart dropdown is-not-empty">
    <span class="ic-cart"></span> 
    <span class="count-cart" style="display:none;"><br><br></span>
    <strong class="minhaCart">minha <span class="compraCart">COMPRA</span></strong>
    <span class="caret-cart"></span><br>
    <div id="header-cart" class="mini-cart-content dropdown-content left-hand skip-content skip-content- -style block-cart block" style="display: none;">
        <span class="msg-carrinho-vazio">&nbsp;&nbsp;Seu carrinho está vazio :(&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o seguinte código `jQuery`:

```
$j('#mini-cart').not('#header-cart').on('click',function(){
    alert('Teste');
});
```

O que eu queria fazer era que quando a `div` com o `id="mini-cart"` fosse clicada, o `alert` seja exibido, porém, se a `div` com o `id="header-cart"` que está dentro da mesma for clicada, o `alert` não pode ser exibido.

Comment: seu seletor está sem sentido, você está dizendo "selecione o elemento com id **mini-cart** que **não** seja o id **header-cart**" não vai funcionar. Precisar fazer um seletor para cada elemento com seu respectivo ID

Comment: @RicardoPontual O que eu queria fazer seria "selecione o elemento com id `mini-cart` menos o elemento com o id `header-cart`", pois o mesmo está dentro da `div`, porém se for clicado, não deve dar `alert` algum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso não vai ser possível fazer isso no seletor, mas você pode verificar isso na *function*. O click traz consigo informações de quem disparou o evento entre outras coisas (leia mais aqui: [evento click](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/click)) , daí é possível identificar se o click veio do elemento que você precisa, e se não for, não executar o código ou ainda cancelar o evento (com `stopPropagation` que é um método do evento, veja mais aqui: [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)). Veja esse exemplo (adaptei um pouco o seu `HTML` para deixar mais evidente cada elemento).

```js
$('#mini-cart').click(function(e) { 
  // recuperar o evento, pelo parâmetro 'e' ou 'event'
  e = e || event;
  // recurar o elemento que gerou o evento
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  
  console.log ('Você clicou no ' + target.id);
  alert ('Você clicou no ' + target.id);
  
  if (target.id != 'mini-cart') {
   // Se clicou em outro elemento dentro de #mini-cart, cancelo o click
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
  }
  
  console.log('Continuando com o evento click...');
  alert('Continuando com o evento click...');
 });
```

```css
.mini-cart {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}

.mini-cart-content {
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mini-cart" class="mini-cart dropdown is-not-empty">
    <span class="ic-cart"></span> 
    <span class="count-cart" style="display:none;"><br><br></span>
    <strong class="minhaCart">minha <span class="compraCart">COMPRA</span></strong>
    <span class="caret-cart"></span><br>
    <div id="header-cart" class="mini-cart-content dropdown-content left-hand skip-content skip-content- -style block-cart block">
        <span class="msg-carrinho-vazio">&nbsp;&nbsp;Seu carrinho está vazio :(&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente resposta! Me ajudou muito! Muito Obrigado!